# Asymptotics of a multi-dimensional Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\alpha\in(0,2]$ and $$f_t(u)=\sum_{m\neq 0}\frac{1}{m^\alpha}\exp(-\|m\|^2 t^2)\exp(im\cdot u),u\in \mathbb R^d.$$
Would anyone know a closed form expression for $f_t(u)$, in all dimension $d$? I actually especially need an expansion with the two first terms as $u\to \infty$.

Here is an attempt with the Poisson summation formula. Let $\varphi_t(m)=t^{-\alpha }\|m\|^{-\alpha}\exp(-\|m^2\|t^2)$. Then we have
$$f_t(u)+1=c_d t^{\alpha }\sum_{j\in \mathbb Z^d}\hat \varphi_t(u+2\pi j)=c_d t^{-d-\alpha}\sum_j\hat \varphi_1(t^{-1}(u+2\pi j))$$

The problem is that this is not valid because $\varphi_1$ is not continuous, I think there is a real problem around 0. I would already be happy for a solution in the case $d=2,\alpha=2,t=0$, i.e. equivalent of $$\sum_{m\neq 0}\frac{e^{imu}}{\|m\|^2}$$

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: The Poisson summation formula, but the Fourier transform is hard to obtain, and I get a sum without complex exponentials but it does not help so much.

Comment: I suppose you could treat the complex exponential as a random phase term, since $u$ is large.

Comment: Ok, what is the approach? How would that give asymptotics?

Comment: a) as a random sum, maybe look at the covariance $|f|^2$

Comment: b) if you add your attempt to the question, I will upvote

Comment: done, thank you

Comment: I don't think there is a smooth asymptotic behavior due to the random phase behavior when $u$ is incommensurate with a rational factor times $\pi$. Note that the expression diverges in $d=2$ if $u$ is a vector of integers times $2\pi$, since $\sum_{m \neq 0} {1\over ||m||^2}$ diverges in 2d

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, it makes sense to look for an expansion as $u\to 0$ (or as $u$ converges to an integer, this is a periodic function).